# Is there a way to get both the prediction probabilities for each class along with the labels for each class in a decision tree classifier?

Tags: python

I want to get the prediction probabilities for each class along with the class labels for a decision tree classifier.

`probs = clf.predict_proba(test)`.

This give me the probabilities and I want to sort to get the top 3 so the code below would give me that:

`best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[-n:]`

But I am unaware how to incorporate the `clf.classes_` along with this to get it all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this does the trick of both sorting the probabilities and also the class labels are obtained

`parts = pd.DataFrame(np.argsort(clf.predict_proba(X_test), axis=1)[-3:], columns=clf.classes_)`